# How to solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{3x^2}{1+x^3}=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{{1+x}}$ and how to find its integrating factor?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{3x^2}{1+x^3}=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{{1+x}}$$ and how to find its integrating factor?

The integrating factor is given as $$\frac{1}{1+x^3}$$.Could'nt understand why.Its not even a linear differential equation.

Comment: Why you need an integration factor? the solution is $y=\int\left(\frac{\sin^2(x)}{{1+x}}+\frac{3x^2}{1+x^3}\right)\,dx$

Comment: You typoed I think. There will be a $y$ beside $3x^2$ and it makes every thing fall into the line..

Comment: Hey what rank did You get . Are you planning to drop or continue?

Comment: a solution in the known elementary functions doesn't exist

Comment: 4341 rank.Yes dropping.Not joining anywhere this year.Maybe i'll get in newer IITS.But no hope of getting good branches in the top 4.So preparing with full determination for 2017.You'll be giving too?Right?Good luck. @ArchisWelankar

Comment: Yeah man so you in race with me;)!